# How to execute Meld using java to compare two files?

Tags: java

is it possible to execute Meld using java to compare two files.
In my java, i have two objects for a files. then i want to compare these files by executing meld programmatically.
Is it possible using java?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? What happened instead of what you expected?

Comment: actually i'm using Meld as stand alone application to compare my files, but i have to do it manually. what i want is to automate this action by execute a java program everyday maybe put it windows task scheduler...

Comment: But if you are running it without somebody looking at it, what is the point? Meld is a GUI application, isn't it?

Comment: i want to integrate in automated test, the first step is to compare two files, if they are not same , i will raise a flag or stop executing my other tests...